# jPlayer audio not working in Chrome but works in Firefox on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, jplayer

We had a strange issue with jPlayer and IIS that I wanted to share and also share the solution that worked for us.

We have a site that's built on C#/VB.NET/ASP.NET. Running off IIS 7.5 (2008 R2 server). Using the jPlayer plugin we were able to get audio (.mp3) working fine in Firefox but would not work in Chrome, Safari or IE8+.

Did some fiddler work and our dev was able to notice that the bytes coming across in Firefox were not coming across in Chrome or IE. So that would explain partially why audio wasn't playing. Headers were not coming across completly for some reason. This is a known issue on the [jPlayer site](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-known-issues) with some HTML5 browsers.

After doing some Google Fu and researching I stumbled on an IIS setting that was worth a try so I did it and it worked! You will need to go into the **HTTP Response Headers** option for that site and add the following setting:

```
Accept-Ranges bytes
```

Where Accept-Ranges is the Name and bytes is the value.

In the web.config file it looks like this:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
     <add name="Accept-Ranges" value="bytes" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Once I added this setting and refreshed my Chrome, Safari and IE8 the audio played successfully.

Did not see this documented anywhere here on SO so wanted to put this post out for those that might encounter a similar issue.

Hope this can help anyone else that might encounter the same issue with jPlayer and IIS. Might save you a couple of hours of research.

Comment: +1 - I wish I could give you a +100. I had the exact same issue and it was driving me nuts!!! However, instead of adding this in the `web.config` I added it as a header in my response like so: `Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");`

Comment: Where to add this in a blazor project? I'm facing the same issue